# Delphi 5 Unknown Publisher Version Info

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, partial-trust

I build a number of executable applications in Delphi 5 which talk to databases over a network. On my Windows 7 PC and other PCs they run without any warning but on some client PCs it gives an 'unknown publisher' warning which doesn't look professional and may be causing other permission issues.

My question is as follows:

- Can anything be added to an application at design time e.g. in Version Info to make it a more trusted application. Is this actually possible in Delphi5?
- Is there anything I must request from Microsoft as an application builder to help them trust my applications?
- Failing the above, how do I disable the 'Trusted Publisher' warning in Windows 7? (apologies this is not a Delphi question)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to sign your executable with a Code Signing security certificate.  That is what the warning is referring to on those client PCs - Windows is not able to verify the integrity of the executable.  The certificate identifies who created the executable, and also ensures that the executable has not been modified after you signed it.

Comment: Thanks Remy. So I need to sign every executable rather than include something in the build... I'll look in to code signing software then. Do you have to pay for it?

Comment: Every executable should be signed, IMO, plus the installer.   You can use Microsoft's SignCode.exe to do the signing, but it's also supported by some installers and build tools such as Visual Build Pro.  I use Commodo certs from K-Software: http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/
It's the best deal that I've found, and the owner (Mitchel Vincent) can walk you through the process and help with any questions that you have.